# Does atomic_load() with memory_order_relaxed introduce any additional overhead compared to simple reading from a variable?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, atomic, c11

I don't see any reason for additional overhead for "native" CPU integrals, but I may be wrong,
so I'd want to hear the comunity's opinion

My real problem concerns some kind of linked list that relatively rare changes but is offten read (similar to typical RCU use case). The idea is to provide 2 access modes for readonly operations: the first mode is used if the structure is now changing (full blown lock free algorithm) and the second lightweight mode for "calm" case (with non-atomic list traversal). For the second (lightweight) case I'm going to use atomic loads with memory_order_relaxed, but if it is too expensive, I need to do some workaround (cahche the atomic value in non-atomic variable, or emulate in some way proposed memory_order_nonatomic   http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1446.htm , etc.)

I understand that the answer depends on atomics implementation (and CPU), but I hope the implementation should behave reasonably :)

Answer (score 5):

[`memory_order_relaxed`](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync) model just allows store/load operations reordering, but it still enforce atomic reads/writes. On some CPU architectures it will lead to bus locking, cache flushing etc. So generally answer is yes - atomic access with `memory_order_relaxed` shall be considered as more expensive than non-atomic access.

Comment: On most CPU simple reading properly aligned machine word preserves data consistency w/o bus locking etc. So a single reason for these actions may be providing the same visible order of events happened with the atomic variable. However, I don't find any explicit requirements in the standards for that. Usually relaxed load is used to acquire the first (expected) value for subsequent CAS operation, but this use case is totally insensitive to possible event order allusions

Comment: Standard requirements are that reads and writes to the relaxed atomic variable are ordered. This is by design for strongly ordered CPUs like x86 and will not produce any overhead comparing to non-atomic access, but could be not true for other architectures which will require memory fence. Also it could bring overhead by disabling compliler optimizations that could lead to reordering.

Comment: @Rost why would relaxed barriers prevent compiler optimizations involving re-ordering...... if they're "relaxed"?

Comment: @user997112 Because "relaxed" affects only ordering and visibility of same variable for different threads. E.g. if you have code `x=42; y=666;` (both x,y are thread local, non-volatile, non-atomic) compiler is free to reorder these writes or even eliminate them. In case of atomics it's not possible - these writes shall be visible to other threads and in same sequence.